# How to display Option List in wishlist sidebar magento

Tags: magento

How to display Option List in wishlist sidebar magento? 
I use this code!
However, it is not working. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
    <div class="truncated">
      <div class="truncated_full_value">
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
      </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php $options = $this->getOptionList(); ?>
<?php if ($options): ?>
<div class="truncated">
<div class="truncated_full_value">
  <div class="item-options">
      <p><?php echo $this->__('Options Details'); ?></p>
      <dl>
          <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
          <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></dt>
          <dd>
              <?php if (is_array($option['value'])): ?>
              <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $option['value'])) ?>
              <?php else: ?>
              <?php echo $option['value'] ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
          </dd>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </dl>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```